# boost::enable_if with arithmetic expression

Tags: boost, enable-if

I have a custom string class with a length as a specialization parameter.  The length should be a minimum of 9 characters and I'd like to make this a compile-time check.

I was hoping to use boost::enable_if for this, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the syntax.  I was hoping there would be something like a boost::is_greater, along the lines of boost::same_as, as below.  But I can't find an expression to put into the enable_if template argument.  Can anyone help?

Unfortunately I can't use C++11 for this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template<int LEN, class Enable = void>
class MyString
{
public:
    char data[LEN];
};

template<int LEN, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_greater<LEN, 8>::type> >
class MyString
{
};

int main()
{
    MyString<4> s;
    return snprintf(s.data, 4, "123");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::enable_if` allows one to exploit [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), which can be helpful in some cases and not appropriate in others. Typically, you want to employ SFINAE when you want to disable certain branches of code depending on some condition without generating a hard compilation error, which often implies that the case will be handled by another branch. For example, one can select a function overload to be called depending on some condition.

```
struct A {};

// This overload gets called for any type T that derives from A or for A itself
template< typename T >
typename boost::enable_if< typename boost::is_base_of< A, T >::type >::type
foo(T const& t);

// This overload is selected for any other types
template< typename T >
typename boost::disable_if< typename boost::is_base_of< A, T >::type >::type
foo(T const& t);
```

Regarding your example, there are few things to note:

- Unlike `std::enable_if` from C++11, `boost::enable_if` and `boost::disable_if` accept a metafunction as its first template argument. A metafunction is a class which has a nested static member variable `value`, which is the result of the metafunction. Boost also provides `boost::enable_if_c` and `boost::disable_if_c` templates, which, like `std::enable_if`, accept the boolean constant directly. So, if you want to check that the length is greater than 8, you can simply write:

```
typename boost::enable_if_c< (LEN > 8) >::type
```

Note that the condition is taken in parenthesis to avoid parsing error, because the greater operator would otherwise be interpreted as the closing angle bracket.

- Some broken compilers have problems with constant expressions like the above. For those compilers it may be necessary to express the condition as a metafunction. [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) can help you with this:

```
typename boost::enable_if<
    boost::mpl::greater<
        boost::mpl::int_< LEN >,
        boost::mpl::int_< 8 >
    >
>::type
```

Here, `boost::mpl::greater` is the metafunction that produces the result of the comparison; this result is picked up by `boost::enable_if`.

- Whichever form you use, it is important that you use the `enable_if<>::type` nested type in the context where a template parameter substitution failure would make the declaration invalid. For classes, this basically amounts to the list of template arguments in the specialization.

```
// Generic template. Used whenever none of the specializations apply.
template< int LEN, class Enable = void >
class MyString
{
};

// Specialization. Used if LEN > 8 is true because
// its second template argument (Enable, which is void by default)
// matches the type produced by enable_if_c, which is also void
// if the condition is true.
template< int LEN >
class MyString< LEN, typename boost::enable_if_c< (LEN > 8) >::type >
{
};
```

So this code effectively selects the specialization depending on the condition. If you want `MyString` to only work for cases when the condition is satisfied, you can leave the main template undefined (i.e. only keep the declaration):

```
// Generic template. Used whenever none of the specializations apply.
template< int LEN, class Enable = void >
class MyString;
```

When you really want to just generate a hard error if some compile-time precondition is violated, it may be more appropriate to use a static assert. In C++11 it is accomplished with [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert), in C++03 you can use [Boost.StaticAssert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html):

```
template< int LEN >
class MyString
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(LEN > 8, "String length must be greater than 8");
};
```

In this case no specializations are needed, and as an added bonus you'll have a nicer error message. In C++03 it'll say something about static assert failure, pointing at the assert line, which explains the problem in plain language. In C++11 the compiler error will contain the message inline.

Comment: Excellent answer, that cleared up a lot of things for me!  Especially thanks for giving me the MPL example that I was incoherently asking for: luckily I don't have to use it, but I knew it must exist and I really wanted to know how to do it.